# Email sender using codeigniter loading inifinity

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i'm trying to send an email using codeigniter but I'm having a problem because whenever I try to send an email, it will stay loading although I successfully send the email.

```
  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->clear();
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from('xxx@live.com');
  $this->email->to('xxx@live.com');
  $this->email->subject('subject');
  $this->email->message('message');
  $this->email->set_alt_message('alternative message');
```

Here's my email configuration.

```
$config =    array('protocol'    => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host'   => 'tcp://smtp.live.com',
    'smtp_port'   => 587,
    'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
    'smtp_user'   => 'xxx@live.com',
    'smtp_pass'   => 'xxxxx',
    'mailtype'    => 'html',
    'wordwrap'    => TRUE);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will stay loading"?

Comment: the page can't proceed to another page.